# Is it possible to dynamically add multiple copies of a subform in Flask-WTForms for registering products?

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

I am developing a simple web application that registers clients, products and sales in a database for the user that is currently logged in. The users, clients and products parts are already completed but I am having trouble handling the wtf forms for products, the way I would intend to (maybe there is a simpler way to code this). The objective is to have a mini ERP system able to handle these transactions.

The following code represents the Sale and SaleBatch models I created, that with the help of SQLALchemy ORM will be correspond to different tables in the DB:

from `models.py`

```py
class Sale(Base):
    """ Sale class """
    __tablename__ = 'sale'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    #timestamp: Mapped[datetime.datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user.id"))
    client_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("client.id"))

    salebatches: Mapped[List["SaleBatch"]] = relationship(backref="sale")

    # Create the init method to ensure that this fields are filled and a row may be created
    def __init__(self, user_id, client_id):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.client_id = client_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Sale {self.id}>'
    
class SaleBatch(Base):
    """ Sale batch class """
    __tablename__ = 'salebatch'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    quantity: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer)
    saleprice: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(Float)
    sale_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("sale.id"))
    product_ref: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("product.ref"))

    def __init__(self, quantity, saleprice, sale_id, product_id):
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.saleprice = saleprice
        self.sale_id = sale_id
        self.product_id = product_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Sale batch {self.id}'
```

The idea was: A sale only has one client, but could have one or more products. So the different sale batches will be "connected" to the sale table that has that specific client.

Now we start to reach the limit of my understanding, but to handle this I thought it will be a good idea to have two different forms, one for the sale and another to be called as many times as the user wants, each corresponding to a different product.

from `forms.py`

```py
class SaleRegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    client = SelectField('Client name', coerce=int, validators=[InputRequired()])

class SaleBatchRegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    product = SelectField('Product name', coerce=int, validators=[InputRequired()])
    quantity = IntegerField('Quantity', validators=[InputRequired()])
    price = DecimalField('Price', validators=[InputRequired()])
```

The following code block represents the app.route that registers the sale:

from `routes.py`

```py
app.route("/registersale", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def registersale():
    id_user = int(current_user.get_id())
    clients_list = get_list_id(Client, id_user)
    sale_form = SaleRegistrationForm()
    sale_form.client.choices = clients_list
    salebatch_form = SaleBatchRegistrationForm()
    product_list = get_list_ref(Product, id_user)
    salebatch_form.choices = product_list

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # register the sale in the db
        flash('Congratulations, you registered a sale.')
        return redirect(url_for('registersale'))
    else:
        return render_template('registersale.html', sale_form=sale_form, salebatch_form=salebatch_form)
```

The `get_list_id` and `get_list_ref` are two simple functions that query the database for all the records that a certain user (per its id_user, 2nd argument) has in a table (1st argument), returning a `list`. The sale registration in the database is not done yet since I am trying to first render the forms and then do this part.

The following HTML extends the `layout.html` file:

```html
{% block main %} 
    <h1>Register sale</h1>
    <sale_form action="" method="post">
        <div class="mb-3">
            {{ sale_form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ sale_form.client.label }}<br>
            {{ sale_form.client }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {% for error in sale_form.client.errors %} 
                <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </sale_form>

    <salebatch_form action="" method="post">
        <div class="mb-3">
            {{ salebatch_form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ salebatch_form.product.label }}<br>
            {{ salebatch_form.product }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {% for error in salebatch_form.product.errors %} 
                <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            {{ salebatch_form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ salebatch_form.quantity.label }}<br>
            {{ salebatch_form.quantity }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {% for error in salebatch_form.quantity.errors %} 
                <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            {{ salebatch_form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ salebatch_form.price.label }}<br>
            {{ salebatch_form.price }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {% for error in salebatch_form.price.errors %} 
                <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </salebatch_form>
{% endblock %}
```

The idea was to create a button to add and remove "lines of products" from the sale registration page, and these "lines of products" correspond to the same `SaleBatchRegistrationForm`, displayed multiple times. I would like to not lose the information previously inserted by the user if he adds any information before pressing the button.
The HTML is not pretty, but for now I just need it to work.

I searched for inspiration but could not find an example close to this. I know there is probably an easy way to implement this in JavaScript but I don't have the knowledge to do that, and besides being a good oportunity to learn, I would like to test if it is possible to use WTF Forms.

I am quite knew to Webdev and any help would be apreciated! Many thanks